# Ruby Debugger code for going into next line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-debug

I am working on ROR app , with ruby debugger. This is my code:

```
def render(d)
  debugger
  folder=d.folders
  folders,empty_folders=check_empty_folder(folder)
  c = cost(folders)
end
```

Now in console the break point at folders=d.folders . Now if i do next near around 30 times  then it come to next line in this function folders,empty_folders  after going through different ruby source file.
Is there any command I can simply go into next line of function in spite of source code.

Comment: what is `d.folders.size` ?

Comment: it keeps of changing mostly it is around 2 and 3.